# WinForms designer error (cannot load resources)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a central DLL with all of our resources, automatically generated.

I have a UserControl that sets some of its properties from that DLL in its constructor. This UserControl loads in the designer just fine.

When I put the UserControl on a form, I cannot open that form in the designer. I get errors such as

> Could not load type 'MyResourceType' from assembly
>   'MyResourceAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>         Instances of this error (1)
>
> 1. Hide Call Stack
>      at MyUserControl..ctor()

Comment: How are you referencing the other dll, project or file reference?

Comment: File, in this case. Changing to project does not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was an old version of the resource DLL in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE folder. Deleting it and its PDB solved the issue.

Comment: Me: copied dll to all places, make sure the most recent version is everywhere. VS: you try to load a dll? No GAC? No problem, i've a 6 months old version lying around in a folder you have never heard of.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: that's not Visual Studio, that's Windows. If you've got a version sitting next to vshost.exe, that's the one taken.

Comment: @Stu : Yes, that's known windows behavior. But it's VS copying the dll to this place.

Answer (score 1):

reason for this problem:

A project is referencing either a class library project or a .dll with its .pdb available.  When the debugger starts another version of the .dll that is referenced is being chosen.  possible solutions, as i also experienced once,

i did like this

- under VS -> tools/options/debugging/symbols  you clear the cache. (Cache symbols in this directory line)
- if you PDB with your dll's, you can copy to the dll location.

may be this will help you.

Comment: Copy them where? The PDBs are there in the bin folder already. And even if I set to only load selected symbols, nothing changes.

Comment: you add pdb and dll in your working directory, and try to rebuild it.

Comment: :O ah.. i mean your project directory,  where is your bin folder, as u already pasted the file's it should compile. try once again rebuilding the class library project, then refer it your Project.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem. And i found out that I have old Dll on this folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE folder.

Soo delete them and it should fix the problem.